# Why Import Fields Instead of Use Text in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, bestpractice

In the salesforce trailhead "Lightning Web Components and Salesforce Data: Use Apex to Work with Data" we have the following code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Name";
import REVENUE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.AnnualRevenue";
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry";
import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts";
const COLUMNS = [
  { label: "Account Name", fieldName: NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text" },
  {
    label: "Annual Revenue",
    fieldName: REVENUE_FIELD.fieldApiName,
    type: "currency"
  },
  { label: "Industry", fieldName: INDUSTRY_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: "text" }
];
export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
  columns = COLUMNS;
  @wire(getAccounts)
  accounts;
}
```

In this example, and in many others, field variables such as FIRST_NAME are imported via the `"@salesforce/schema/` methodology. Later, they are referenced via code such as `REVENUE_FIELD.fieldApiName`.

Why is this? Is there a technical reason for it? Is it just a syntax standard? Given that the api name is already hardcoded via the `import` lines, why not just move that coding directly to where the API names are referenced? Something like this:

```
const COLUMNS = [
  { label: "Account Name", fieldName: 'Name', type: "text" },
  { label: "Annual Revenue", fieldName: "AnnualRevenue", type: "currency" },
  { label: "Industry", fieldName: "Industry", type: "text" }
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the [@salesforce/schmea docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_schema), there's many benefits:

1. Salesforce verifies that the objects and fields exist. It'll catch typos of the API name as well
2. Prevents used objects/fields from being deleted
3. The big benefit: **Cascades any renamed objects and fields into your component's source code**. This means if you change the API name of the field it'll automatically change in your LWC without you having to search and replace it if it was hard-coded.